# button.value is not changing the text value of button

Tags: javascript, html, object

I have this code in my javascript. It creates the button and has the onclick functionality but the .value doesn't work

```
var button = document.createElement("button");
button.value = "+";
button.onclick = addBox;
document.getElementById("section").appendChild(button);
```

Comment: Can you add what you mean by "`.value` doesn't work"? What are you expecting?

Comment: Can you show your `addBox` function too?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please try and elaborate on your question. Saying something "doesn't work" is no where near descriptive enough for other users to provide a correct answer. What are you trying to achieve? What have you tried?

Comment: this is the addBox function @super-cool-handsome-gel-boy.

Comment: @Yunath (please edit the question when you have new code)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not `value` but `textContent`. If you use value, you need to use `<input type="button" />`. `Button`'s text is in the `textContent`.

Why `textContent` and not `innerHTML`, because `textContent` is faster, it not tries to parse into `html`.

```js
var button = document.createElement("button");
button.textContent = "+";
document.getElementById("section").appendChild(button);
```

```html
<div id="section">
  
</div>
```

For **input with type=button**

```js
var button = document.createElement("input");
button.type = "button"
button.value = "+";
document.getElementById("section").appendChild(button);
```

```html
<div id="section">
  
</div>
```

Comment: You can also use .̶i̶n̶n̶e̶r̶T̶e̶x̶t̶ `.textContent`. `.value` is valid on the button, but it just doesn't show as text.

Comment: More "correctly": `button.appendChild(document.createTextNode("+"));`

Comment: @evolutionxbox `innerText` is old-IE only. You want `textContent`